# Solving separating differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$7e^{-s}(1+\frac{ds}{dt} )=6 $

My solution is wrong, and I dont see where I am making mistake.

$\frac{1}{\frac{6}{7e^{-s}-1} }ds=dt$

$\frac{7e^{-s}}{6-7e^{-s}}ds=dt $

$6-7e^{-s}=u$

$7e^{-s}=6-u$

$ds=\frac{du}{6-u} $

$t=ln(6-7e^{-s})+C$

Comment: denominator in line 4 is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think already your first transformation is wrong. I get, avoiding double fractions,
$$
1+\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac67 e^s\\
\frac{ds}{\frac67 e^s-1}=dt\\
\frac{d(e^{-s}-\frac67)}{e^{-s}-\frac67}=dt
\\
e^{-s}-\frac67=C·e^{t},\\
s=-\ln(\frac67+C·e^{t})
$$

Comment: How did you from 2. step get to the 3.?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your solution is correct up to your expression for $u$. From here, you want

$$du = 6\mathrm{e}^{s}ds$$

$$ds = \frac{du}{6\mathrm{e}^{s}} = \frac{du}{u+7}$$